# How to assert contents written to io.BytesIO in unit tests

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest

Assume the following minimal code:

```
def upload(fileobj, key):
    # e.g. S3.Bucket.upload_fileobj()
    pass

def work():
    with io.BytesIO() as tmp:
        tmp.write(b'abc')  # here can be a tarfile created
        upload(tmp, "file")
```

I would like to assert the contents of `tmp` in unit tests. How to do it correctly?

This way does not work:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
upload = MagicMock()

work()

with upload.mock_calls[0][1][0] as f:
     f.readlines() # ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: The BytesIO object is closed and discarded as soon as `work` returns.  You would either have to download the resulting file yourself, or use `tmp = io.BytesIO()` instead of the `with` and return `tmp` from the function.  Then, use `valid = work()`, and you can rewind and read `valid`'.

Comment: Hmm.. I'd like to avoid uploading such file anywhere, and also not closing that file in a production code looks a little bit troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out one solution by myself (thanks to Tim Roberts inspirations in comments), which is using [`side_effect` option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) (of `unittest.mock.MagicMock` constructor).

```
import unittest.mock

eavesdropped = []
def upload_mock(fileobj, key):
    fileobj.seek(0)
    eavesdropped.append(fileobj.read())

with unittest.mock.patch('__main__.upload', side_effect=upload_mock) as upl:
    work()
    assert eavesdropped[0] == b'abc'

    work()
    assert eavesdropped[1] == b'abc'
```